# Not able to proceed with ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have MySQL database having columns named with roomno, availability, clean_status, price and room_type. Column Availability has data as either 'available' or 'not available' and column clean_status has data as either 'dirty' or 'cleaned'. I am trying to fetch data from database and if the selected room is either 'not available' or 'dirty', I would like to show error message stating 'room should be available or cleaned before adding customer'. I have used ResultSet and execute the work. Earlier it showed the error message. I modified the code and made it executable, but it doesn't give any error message neither the data in column of database has changed. I think it is because of ResultSet. Can any body help me?

```
try {
    connection = new MySQLConnection();
} catch (Exception ae) {
    if (ae != null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Connection To Database");
    }
}
String avai ="select availability from rooms where roomno='"+roomno+"'";
String clean ="select clean_status from rooms where roomno='"+roomno+"'";

   try {
       this.see = connection.s.executeQuery(clean);
   }
   catch (SQLException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
try {
    this.conn = new MySQLConnection();
  this.se = connection.s.executeQuery(avai);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
    if (se.equals("Available") && see.equals("Cleaned")){
        String str = "insert into customer values('" +id + "','" +mobileno +"','" +name +"','" +gender+"','"+country+"','" +roomno+"','"+checkedin+"','" +deposit+"')";
        try {
            connection.s.executeUpdate(str);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Added To Database");
        }
        catch (Exception eu) {
            eu.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error In Database Table", "Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    else if (se.equals("Not Available") || see.equals("Dirty")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Room Is Dirty or Not Available");
    }
```

Comment: `se` and `see` are result sets, so they are never equal to `"Available"` or `"Cleaned"`. I recommend that you read a tutorial or book on using JDBC before continuing. Also, don't concatenate values into a query string: it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

From your code **se acd see** are the respective  ResultSet obtained, I am not sure how ResultSet.equals works, but I suggest you use the following

```
while(see.next())
{
String clean=see.getString("clean_status");
}
while(se.next())
{
String avail=see.getString("availability");
}
```

And then check the output.

However,if the error still persists, check in the table if the values for availability and clean_status are having any leading or trailing spaces, which could be an issue at times.

Comment: ```see = connection.s.executeQuery(clean);
                           while(see.next())
                           {clean=see.getString("clean_status");
                               this.clean=clean;
                           }
                           se = connection.s.executeQuery(avai);
                           while(se.next())
                           {
                               avail=se.getString("availability");
                               this.avail=avail;
```This worked well. But it doesn't work for ResultSet.equals. Anyway I got solution thanks.